# PHP printf adds something after formatted string

Tags: php, printf

When im using printf,

```
printf("%.2f zł", 20.4);
```

it returns

```
20.40 zł9
```

but i want

```
20.40 zł
```

When i use `sprintf("%.2f zł", 20.4)` there is no problem.

`zł` is polish currency symbol. When i replace "ł" with "l" i still have problem like this, so it looks like this is not related with encoding.

**How can I use printf for currency correctly?**

Comment: looks not http://codepad.org/dAWs6yDQ

Comment: Does `printf("%.2f %s", 20.4, 'zł');` produce the same weird output?  I'd test, but I can't paste unicode into my shell for some reason...

Comment: @Charles yes, when i add "zł" as parameter it produces same (wrong) output.

Comment: Consider using `number_format()` where you can change decimal and thousands separator to adjust it for polish standard.

Comment: Thanks @dev-null-dweller, i used number_format() and it works great. I can use "polish" fraction separator as well ("," instead of ".").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

I wrote:

```
echo printf(...);
```

instead of just:

```
printf(...);
```

After string produced by printf() i got that string length, which is value returned by printf (in fact - added number was 9 in case of 123.45 value, in 20.4 case it was number 8).

Comment: Ah, nice find! The return type of printf() is not too well known. It appears to be [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php), though.

Comment: I found it by researching differences between printf and sprintf (sprintf does not return length).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the 9 is not the result of a different print, happening further on in your code? Try commenting out this printf line and seeing if the 9 is still there.

If replacing the polish character by a regular L does not fix it, you correctly assessed that it isn't an encoding problem.

The only difference between `printf()` and `sprintf()` I can think of seems to be the way they return the result: `printf` outputs to the HTML buffer while `sprintf` returns a string.